# Batch file to import certificate issue

Tags: batch-file, command-line, batch-processing

I have a situation wherein I have to import number of certificates on a webserver. I am intending to do it via a batch program. I have written the following batch program

```
    @echo off
    for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in (cert.txt) do (
    for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%b in (password.txt) do (
    certutil -p %%b -importpfx "C:\Install\Certificates\%%a.pfx"
    )
    )
Pause
```

This seems to work on most of the certificates however it doesn't import a certificate with "space" as a character. Please also let me know if there are any other characters I need to be concerned about.

Answer (score 0):

```
certutil -p "%%b" -importpfx "C:\Install\Certificates\%%a.pfx"
```

(untried - should work)

Comment: :- I have tried this but it says expected 2 arguments but found 5, please note my passworf is ` 《|$@&as {><

Comment: :- Please note that the first chracter of the password is ` second is a space. Please help..

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

certutil -f -p "password" -importpfx "certificate.pfx"

You may have to include the full path of the certificate in the final parameter.